# How to create a class(Rectangle) with a paint method (like drawRectangle) that is called from a button in Form1

Tags: c#, class, graphics, paint

I re-explain my question here. All my code here works. It generates ellipse, rectangles and lines on button_click. My programming teacher wants me to put the code from btnLijn, btnCirkel and btnRechthoek in differant classes. The reason is that it looks more neat.

Also I am having another problem. The problem is that I can only generate 1 graphic at the time. Everytime I want to add one.. the old one disappears. How to fix these problems?

namespace Kunstgenerator

{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool TekenCirkel = false;

    bool TekenRechthoek = false;
    bool TekenLijn = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void btnCirkel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TekenCirkel = true;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        TekenCirkel = false;
    }

    private void btnRechthoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TekenRechthoek = true;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        TekenRechthoek = false;
    }

    private void btnLijn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TekenLijn = true;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        TekenLijn = false;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       // Er wordt een Random aangemaakt.
       Random random = new Random();

       // Breedte en hoogte wordt aangemaakt en verwezen naar zichzelf.
       // Hier wordt de Random gebruikt om een willekeurige hoogte en breedte te maken.
       int canvasHoogte = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height;
       int canvasBreedte = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width;

       int lengte = random.Next(0, 125);
       int X = random.Next(this.Width / 3);
       int Y = random.Next(this.Height / 3);

       // Primaire kleuren Rood, Geel, Blauw worden hier aangemaakt.
       // Door de Random is de kleuren willekeurig. Er wordt een kleur uitgekozen tussen 1 en 255
       int r = random.Next(255);
       int g = random.Next(255);
       int b = random.Next(255);

       if (TekenRechthoek)
       {
           Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
           if (random.Next(2) == 0)
           {
               graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)), X, Y, lengte, lengte );
           }
           else
           {
               graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))), X, Y, lengte, lengte);
           }
       }
       else if (TekenLijn)
       {
           Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
           graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))), X, Y, lengte, lengte);
       }
       else if (TekenCirkel)
       {
            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
            if (random.Next(2) == 0)
            {
                graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)), X, Y, lengte, lengte);
            }
            else
            {
                graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))), X, Y, lengte, lengte);
            }
        }
      }          
   }
```

}

Comment: if you want to draw a rect in form paint, draw it in form paint.  You could add a `Draw` method` to your Rect version, but you *want* to use the graphics provided by the paint event so it draws where it is supposed to.

Comment: Ye I think I know what you mean. I found this post on stackoverflow. This is the thing that I want. But I don't get the post. If you or someone else could explain this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055722/paint-a-method-from-another-class

Comment: the linked answer is saying the same thing I just did.  Your rect can contain the draw code (trivial), but it will need the Graphics object from the paint event of the object you wish to draw onto.

Comment: Thanks for reply,

okay. I think I get it a little more. Could I ask of you, if you got the time ofcourse to show me a demonstration of it?

Comment: No, I will not code an answer from scratch,  Post what you have, describe how it fails and we can go from there.

Comment: I want to let you know that I have edited my post. This time I edited my question a bit. If you got the time to look at it would be great :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

edit: looks like i totally misunderstood the question.

as per the link you put above. what they are saying is that inside the form_paint event, instead of creating a new Graphic's instance, you should use the existing one. e is an instance of EventsArgs that is passed by the form on the event trigger

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //<- e is there
    {
    }
```

so you would want to use the instance of the class Graphics from that EventArgs

the fixed implementation of code would look something like this

```
public class Form1
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //<- e is there
    {
        Draw(e.Graphics);
    }
}

public class Object : Form1
{   
    public void Draw(Graphics mapGraphics)
    {
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
        mapGraphics.FillEllipse(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 12, 12));

    }
}
```

(this wont compile because the generic eventArgs e doesnt have a Graphics property but it should explain what needs to happen for it to work).

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I knew this ye. What I want is to create a new Graphics object in rectangle class. But this is (in my opinion) not possible, because the new class does not have a Paint event :(

Comment: edited my response. unfortunately you need to use the preexisting EventArgs to properly translate changes back to the proper object.

Answer (score 0):

In future questions, please refer your own code...
Because I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but here goes.

If you want to create a new instance of your class `Rectangle` when you click on your button,
just add the following code to the button click event:

```
private void your_Btn_Click_Event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(){};
}
```

This will create an instance of your class when clicking on the button and thus all the functionality you defined in your class, is available to you.

You can access the button click event WPF viewer, selecting the desired button, and double clicking on the empty space of the "Click" event. This should automatically create an event handler for you.